# Alias for function

Tags: c#, function, winapi, alias, extern

I want to import some functions from kernel32.dll, but I want to use different names. Example function:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")] private static extern bool ReadProcessMemoryProc64 (...);

private static bool BetterReadableAndWriteableName (...) {
    ReadProcessMemoryProc64(...);
}
```

Wrapping the function is what I actually don't want, if there is another way.

Comment: You can do this but it's probably a bad idea. How will the next reader of your code know what these functions are?

Comment: There are valid cases. For example, many Win32 APIs have LPVOID/LPARAM/etc parameters (e.g. SendMessage) that can take different data types depending upon other parameters. In this case, it is often necessary to create different method signatures to support different use cases. In that case, you must use EntryPoint to rename the function (or you could declare them in different classes to avoid the name collision, but that's not always appropriate).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the [EntryPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.entrypoint.aspx) property of DllImportAttribute.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint="ReadProcessMemoryProc64")]
private static extern bool BetterReadableAndWriteableName (...);
```

Comment: Thank you both :) I tried many solutions, but this is so simple -_-

Answer (score 7):

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "ReadProcessMemoryProc64")] 
private static extern bool MyName(...);
```