# Is it safe to rename extern method parameters in C#?

Tags: c#, dll, unmanaged

I am currently cleaning up some of our legacy code base in which we make use of `extern` methods. The parameter names are all over the place in terms of naming conventions. I'd like to consolidate them.

#### Example

```
[DllImport("customdll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void SetStatus(int new_status);
```

Can I safely rename `new_status` to `newStatus` or will that break the contract?

ReSharper suggests it as a change, but I'd like to verify it. I was not able to find documentation on it (for or against it).

I am *not* asking if renaming the method name itself is possible, just the parameter definitions.

#### References

- [Alias for function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005017/alias-for-function)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to change the name of the parameters (but not the method itself) as long as you keep them in the same order with the proper data types. Parameters in traditional DLLs are populated by ordinal, not by name.

You can also change the name of the method itself if you use the [EntryPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.entrypoint?view=netframework-4.7) parameter in the DllImport constructor.

Comment: Great, I was hoping it would be the case. Thanks for also referring to the `EntryPoint` parameter of the `DllImport` attribute.